# XPath to check the namespace a prefix is bound to

Tags: java, xpath

Say I have the following XML file:

```
<a xmlns:foo="http://foo"></a>
```

I need to check whether the prefix `foo` is bound to `http://foo` or not. Whereby *not bound* could indicate that the said prefix does not exist at all or is bound to some other namespace URI.
I already have a library that takes a [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html) object and an XPath expression and returns a (possibly empty) `List` of [Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html)s that exist at that XPath.

So what would be an expression that would check for the presence of a prefix `foo` in the top-most element (document element) bound to the namespace `http://foo` and that would yield one node for the above XML and zero nodes for the following XMLs:

```
<a xmlns:fooX="http://foo"></a>
```

and

```
< xmlns:foo="http://fooX"></a>
```

I tried, as a first step, to just get the value of that attribute using:

```
/*[@*[local-name()='foo']]
```

... but it seems that prefix-binding attributes are handled differently from "normal" attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it with XPath then you have to use the namespace axis: `/*[namespace::foo[. = 'http://foo']]`. DOM Level 3 might provide different ways treating the namespace declarations as attributes and resolving prefixes, see http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-lookupNamespaceURI.